# Dapper stored procedure mapping to complex object

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have an `ImageLink` object that consists of an `Image` object and a `Link` object, and a SQL stored procedure that returns the needed values, but I can't get the Dapper mapping to work.

Simplified it's like this:

```
class ImageLink() 
{
    ImageItem Image { get; set; }
    LinkItem Link { get; set; }
}

class ImageItem() 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class LinkItem() 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string LinkText { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var results = await conn.QueryAsync<ImageLink>("GetImageLinkItems", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

But that didn't work, so I've attempted various MultipleMappings e.g.

```
var results = await conn.QueryAsync<ImageLink, ImageItem, LinkItem, ImageLink>("IVC.GetImageLinkItems", 
(il, ii, li)=> { il.Image.Id = ii.Id; il.Link.Id = li.Id; return il; },
commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

with and without the 'splitOn' option.

The best I got was to get the `Image` object returned, but without the `Link` object info.

SQL Server, simplified query, (I've also tried returning aliased column names)

```
SELECT  i.Id, i.Name, l.Id, l.LinkText
    FROM    Links l JOIN Images i on i.Id = l.ImageId
    ORDER BY l.SeqNo
```

How do I get my `ImageLink` object populated?

Comment: Which **RDBMS** is this for? And what does the stored procedure look like, e.g. which columns does it return in what way?

Comment: @marc_s question edited, it's SQL Server and I've added the current proc to match the simplified objects.

Answer (score -2):

Since you dont have any `ImageLink`'s in the database, I suggest you remove them from the `Query` generic parameters.

```cs
var results = await conn.QueryAsync<ImageItem, LinkItem, ImageLink>("IVC.GetImageLinkItems", 
    (il, ii, li)=> { return new ImageLink { ImageItem = ii, LinkItem = li }, 
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```